# Cannot upload image on mosaico template

Tags: error, mosaico

The issue occurs when attempting to upload an image in the template builder. We receive the message "Unexpected upload error (Service unavailable (with message))". It also writes to the Drupal log:

Error: Class 'Imagick' not found in CRM_Mosaico_Utils::processUpload() (line 231 of /home/pillar/public_html/sites/default/files/extensions/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/CRM/Mosaico/Utils.php).

Anyone knows if there's any fix for this please? Thanks

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/312

Comment: This fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

You need Imagick package for Mosaico to work. If you already have the package installed then i believe its should be related to SE post [Failed to locate Mosaico graphics driver](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30856/failed-to-locate-mosaico-graphics-driver/31270#31270)

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. I have imagick installed and other SE post doesn’t help.

Comment: You also need to ensure Imagick is enabled for your specific version of PHP. I received this error last week and just had to switch Imagick from 5.x to 7.2. Contact your host provider and they can do this for you.