# Mosaico not loading!

Tags: mosaico

Yesterday I prepared a Mosaico mailing for approval. Today I was going to send it. But when I go to the mailing page, I get this error: "Mosaico cannot be displayed because this system does not meet all requirements. For details, check the System Status."

System Status has this warning:
"Graphics driver not available
Mosaico requires a graphics driver such as PHP-ImageMagick or PHP-GD. For more information, see Mosaico Settings.
Error: Failed to locate Mosaico graphics driver. Either "mosaico_graphics" is invalid or the autodetection failed."

Mosaico Settings gives me no options or useful information, which is weird:

[image]

I'm running on PHP 7.2, and my host's PHP extensions include ImageMagick for 7.2.

I have made no changes or updates to Civi or the host in the past 24 hours, so I am baffled as to what has broken Mosaico, but I need to get this mailing out ASAP!

Any advice out there?

Comment: I went into the db and manually created a Mailing Job to get it sent (the message didn't require editing), so my urgency is relieved. But I'm still going to want to use Mosaico at some point!

Comment: Do you have full control over your server, or does a host do software updates on the server? While you may not have made changes, the host may have. I've had issues where they upgraded something on the server that I was using and now it was an unsupported version, was now in a new location, etc.

Comment: This might help: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30856/failed-to-locate-mosaico-graphics-driver

Comment: OMG, @Aidan, I even commented on that thread! smh. My issue then was after an update, and Cleaning Up the caches worked for me. Trying to do that today, and I discovered that the problem is solved BEFORE I cleaned up the caches. So, my guess is it was either 1) it was a server host issue (as per @jenni-simonis) or 2) the caches were cleaned up automatically when expired.

Comment: ... well I wasn't going to mention that you commented on that post :-)  Good to hear it's working now.